# hbase values reading using scala, conversion problem

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, apache-phoenix

I'm using scala to read numerical data from Hbase columns, which were previously filled via Phoenix. I can read the column values but when I convert them to String, instead of real numbers I still have byte values, so the String filled with some non-printable values.

I assume the problem is in conversion while I map RDD.
Here is the code I use to map my RDD:

```
val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result])

  val stocksRdd = hBaseRDD.map {
  case (key: ImmutableBytesWritable, value: Result) =>

    (new String(value.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(indVarFamCol), Bytes.toBytes(indVar))),
    new String(value.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(depVarFamCol), Bytes.toBytes(depVar))))

}
stocksRdd.take(10).foreach(println)
```

My actual result is:

(�,�)
(�,�)
(�,�)
(�,�)
.....

However it should be:

(5,5)
(23,55)
(12,234)
(23,55)
.....

The hbase table entry, I'm reading, looks in the following way:

\x80\x00\x07x                                                 column=0:YEARSOFEDU, timestamp=1555763290217, value=\x80\x00\x00\x10

My task is to read the value and convert into String to see the actual number.

I'm relatively new in HBASE and scala so any clarifications will be much appreciated.

Thank you